# I have created class need help associating the class for values

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

Not sure if I made sense in the title, but I have created classes and now I need to associate a class with a number. For example 1 would be the penny (object) and with this object I have associated height and weight. I need help asking how to associate this class with the number 1.

I know i need to have it ask the question like something like so

```
print "Enter 1 for Penny\nEnter 5 for Nickel\nEnter 10 for Dime\nEnter 25 for Quarter\nEnter 50 for halfdollar\nEnter 100 for Dollar"
```

I need it to then ask me to Enter number:
Than ask how many of that coin of the number you just entered:
Than give me the total weight
Than give me the total height

with that should I include it in that original print statement or should I do another print statement or just keep it like so...

```
print "Enter 1 for Penny\nEnter 5 for Nickel\nEnter 10 for Dime\nEnter 25 for Quarter\nEnter 50 for halfdollar\nEnter 100 for Dollar\nEnter how many coins"
```

Now witht the last part of enter how many coins how do I associate that with a class I have a class set up for Penny for instance like so

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# Defining a class
class Coin():
    def __init__(slef,weight,height):
      self.weight = weight
      self.height = height

class Penny(Coin)
  def __init__(self)
    Coin.__init__(self,2.500,1.52)
    Penny = 1

class Nickel(Coin):
  def __init__(self):
    Coin.__init__(self,5.00,1.95)
    Nicke = 5

class Dime(Coin):
  def __init__(self):
    Coin.__init__(self,2.268,1.35)
    Dime = 10

class Quarter(Coin):
  def __init__(self):
    Coin.__init__(self,5.670,1.75)
    Quarter = 25

class HalfDollar(Coin):
  def __init__(self):
    Coin.__init__(self,11.34,2.15)
    HalfDollar = 50

class Dollar(Coin):
  def __init__(self):
    Coin.__init__(self,8.10,2.00)
    Dollar = 100
 print "Enter 1 for Penny\nEnter 5 for Nickel\nEnter 10 for Dime\nEnter 25 for Quarter\nEnter 50 for halfdollar\nEnter 100 for Dollar\n"
 print "Please enter a number:"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
class Coin():
    def __init__(self, name, value, weight, height):
      self.name = name
      self.value = value
      self.weight = weight
      self.height = height

definitions = [("dollar", 100, 8.1, 2.0), ...] # define the coins

coins = {data[1]: Coin(*data) for data in definitions} # create Coin instances
```

There is no need for the `Dollar` to be a sub-class of `Coin`, you can just make it an instance with appropriate attribute values.

You can now access each `Coin` instance within `coins` by value:

```
dollar = coins[100]
```

or use it to access the name:

```
for value in sorted(coins):
    print("Enter {0.value} for a {0.name}".format(coins[value]))
coin_value = int(raw_input("Pick a coin: "))
coin = coins[coin_value]
coin_count = int(raw_input("How many {0}: ".format("{0.name}s".format(coin)
                                                   if coin.value > 1 else
                                                   "pennies")))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you name it something generic like `cents`, you can create a lookup table as follows:

```
lookup_table = {Penny.cents: Penny, Nickle.cents: Nickle, Dime.cents: Dime, ... }
coin = lookup_table[number_user_entered]()
```

That way you can dynamically create an instance of the proper class based on the user input.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are both good other ways of dealing with your problem. To strictly solve it the way you defined it:

```
class Coin():
    def __init__(self, weight, height):
        self.weight = weight
        self.height = height

class Penny(Coin):
    value = 1
    def __init__(self):
        Coin.__init__(self, 2.500, 1.52)

class Nickel(Coin):
    value=5
    def __init__(self):
        Coin.__init__(self, 5.00, 1.95)

class Dime(Coin):
    value=10
    def __init__(self):
        Coin.__init__(self, 2.268, 1.35)

class Quarter(Coin):
    value=25
    def __init__(self):
        Coin.__init__(self, 5.670, 1.75)

class HalfDollar(Coin):
    value=50
    def __init__(self):
        Coin.__init__(self, 11.34, 2.15)

class Dollar(Coin):
    value=100
    def __init__(self):
        Coin.__init__(self, 8.10, 2.00)

mycoin = Penny()
print "A penny is worth", mycoin.value

yourcoin = Quarter()
print "A quarter is worth", yourcoin.value

association = {str(class_obj.value): class_obj for class_obj in (Penny, Nickel, Dime, Quarter, HalfDollar, Dollar)}

print "Enter 1 for Penny\nEnter 5 for Nickel\nEnter 10 for Dime\nEnter 25 for Quarter\nEnter 50 for halfdollar\nEnter 100 for Dollar\n"
value = raw_input("Please enter a number:")
number = raw_input("How many of that coin:")

if value in association:
    mycoin = association[value]()
    print "total weight:", mycoin.weight * int(number)
    print "total height:", mycoin.height * int(number)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this does solve the OP's problem; I think they want to be able to access the coin by value, not vice versa

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the coin type and amount of coins into a dictionary of a single multidimensional list:

```
coins = {1:[Penny,[]], 5:[Nickel,[]], 10:[Dime,[]]} # etc...
```

Then, when you ask the user for coin type and amount, take that value as the key lookup for the dictionary and append that many coins to its list, instantiating the class in the process:

```
coin_type = raw_input("Enter 1 for Penny\nEnter 5 for Nickel\nEnter 10 for Dime\n:")
coin_amnt = raw_input("Enter amount: ")
for i in range(coin_amnt):
    coins[coin_type][1].append(coins[coin_type][0]())
```

To check total amount of a coin type:

```
len(coins[coin_type][1])
```

To check individual instances of a coin type:

```
for c in coins[coin_type][1]:
    print c.weight, c.height
```

If you wanted to print a coin's type, you can add a __str__() special method to each of your coin classes, and then print the instance as you loop the list.

Hope this helps.